Selenium IWebDriver(ChromeDriver) doesn't work properly when another window is open
Here is my code that works properly.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        options.AddArgument(@"profile-directory=Default");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

The problem is it works fine unless I open another Chrome window before I run it. When I open a window after I run my code I get this error.

13.08.2024 16:52:35 session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (SessionNotCreated)


I had the exactly same issue trying to run multiple Chrome instances simultaneously. The main issue with the Chrome profile directory. Basically, when you run a Chrome instance with a defined profile directory (like you done at your codebase), it lock that particular profile directory to access from other instances.
The solution is that, you can run multiple instances using different profile directories. i.e. for each Chrome instance you need to use different chrome profile. Below is my Python Codebase for your reference
debugPort = random.randint(9222,9298)
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-port={debugPort}")
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=/home/user/my_env/{profile_name}")

IMPORTANT: You need to assign different debug PORTs for different profiles too.

I have to use profiledirectory codebase for some reason. I can't use it like that
